# ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist

Tags: shell, hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera, hue

i am running pig script from shell script and i am concatenating 50 files and putting it in hdfs, but when i try to load the file using pig script i am getting error as

> ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist:

but the file is there and when i try to delete the file i am getting an error message in hue that is :

> Cannot perform operation. Note: you are a Hue admin but not a HDFS superuser, "hdfs" or part of HDFS supergroup, "supergroup".
>   [Errno 2] File /user/cloudera/xxxx/xxxx not found

Please help as i am struggling in this.
i am using cloudera 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only `hdfs` user or directory owner can delete files from HDFS. So create new user called hdfs, then try to do your operations

If you want to do this on CLI try below

`sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -rmr /path/to/file`